# jquery add() and binding events

Tags: jquery

If I have following in jQuery $("#someId").add("#someOtherId").bind("click", function(e) {...
I get the click bound only to the last element. How can I use add() and bind all elements to some event?

Comment: I don't get how you manage only to bind the last element, you should bind both with that syntax.

Comment: Darn it, I had a typo in a first element. I still learned something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest solution?

```
$("#someId, #someOtherId").click(function(e) { ... });
```

Multiple selectors can be separated by commas.

Alternate solution? Use [`andSelf()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/andSelf):

```
$("#someId").add("#someOtherId").andSelf().click(function(e) { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why that is a problem, but in this case you should be able to use the following:

```
$("#someId, #someOtherId").bind("click", function(e) {...
```

You can add multiple selectors by separating them with a comma.